# Is there a way to search for games on Steam that are both Mac OS and PS4 controller compatible?

Tags: steam, ps4, controllers, macos

I'm having a hard time finding games that meet these requirements. At the moment I spend a long time downloading a game only to find it won't work with a handheld controller. Can I search by this compatibility, or does anyone have a list published anywhere of eligible titles? Thanks!

Comment: @Batophobia Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, partially. Steam search has a built-in filter feature, [this URL](https://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=28&os=mac) will give you games:

- That you haven't ignored [if you're logged in]
- That are not in your library [if you're logged in]
- That have full controller support (not only PS4, but controller. You can't specify PS4 controller. Should be fine, still)
- That are for macOS

You can improve the search by editing the filters on the [right side menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaDJr.png). And you can read more about the search features in [this announcement](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1714119088658959584).

Comment: [SteamLabs](https://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/steam/store/), a third-party site, also has some support for this. And [PCGamingWiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderlands_3) has "Controller [Support]" and detailed "Controller Types" info listed for many games, especially the most popular ones. So, @Phil Brooks, you could find games you like with controller support and look them up on PCGW to make sure they support PS4 controllers.